# How to use a Markdown-it plugin without Node or require.js

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I am trying to use the [markdown-it-footnote](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-footnote) extension for the [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) JS parser.

The readme gives an example of how to install it when using node.js:

```
var md = require('markdown-it')()
            .use(require('markdown-it-footnote'));

md.render(/*...*/) // See examples above
```

However I am not using node.js (and have never done so far). How can I embed the extension directly into the HTML-document?

I use the markdown-it-parser as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/markdown-it/8.2.2/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var md = window.markdownit();
md.render(...);
</script>
```

The markdown-it-footnote-readme also states:

> If you load script directly into the page, without package system,
>   module will add itself globally as window.markdownitFootnote.

I tried to use it in many ways but was not successful:

```
var md = window.markdownit();
md = window.markdownitFootnote();
```

or

```
var md = window.markdownit().markdownitFootnote;
```

or

```
var md = window.markdownit(window.markdownitFootnote);
```

...

Comment: as the message states you should be able to access it like this: `window.markdownitFootnote`

Answer (score 8):

I just found the solution. Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var md = window.markdownit().use(markdownitFootnote);
</script>
```

Comment: note: you can also `window.markdownitFootnote` or just `markdownit().use(markdownitFootnote);`

Comment: @JoelHarkes Great! Thanks.

Comment: @JoelHarkes Could you elaborate please, what are the pros and cons of specifying `window` object here? I.e. `var md = window.markdownit()...` vs. `var md = markdownit()...`

Comment: @johnc.j. if you google you'll probably find a better explanation. but in short: `window` is the global scope variables. If you don't specify it it could be i define `var markdownit = 2` in my function and then it will try to call the function on this variable instead. and if it doesn't find it, it will go up in scope until it reaches the global scope to find the variable. using `window.markdown` will force always to take the global scope.